# UIImagePickerController iPhone Camera crop overlay

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

How do I use UIImagePickerController to show a overlay (say a small circle)?

Also when the user clicks the picture, only the part of the photo inside the circle is returned, how do I go about that?

Comment: Hava a look on this example: http://www.musicalgeometry.com/archives/821

Comment: I rephrased the question with a illustration here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545362/cameraoverlayview-to-crop-the-result-in-uiimagepickercontroller