# cameraOverlayView to crop the result in UIImagePickerController

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller, ios

When I use `UIImagePickerController` with `cameraOverlayView`, can I get the only a selective region from my overlay view?

http://tinyurl.com/2fqy9nq

Comment: which class is cameraoverlayview?

Comment: @Phil: `cameraOverlayView` is a property of the image picker controller, exposed simply as a `UIView`: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImagePickerController/cameraOverlayView

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Add an UIImageView as child to your cameraOverlayView.
2. Create a black PNG image size 320x480. Cut a rectangle in the middle to produce a hole (transparent pixels).
3. Assign the PNG image to the UIImageView.

Alternatively you could overwrite your cameraOverlayView's `- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect` like this (untested out of my head):

```
// Request draw context
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

// Draw background        
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

// Cut hole
CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeClear);
CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(40, 40, 100, 100);
```

I have done something similar in my Faces app (http://faces.pixelshed.net/). Feel free to write a comment if one of the steps seems unclear.